# How did the Apollo engineers decide what to include in their cargo?

Tags: apollo-program, payload

The Apollo missions, like all missions really, were limited in what they could bring into space. How did they decide what would make the trip? Were there any tests or failures that they learned from?

Comment: Are you talking about scientific payload, for use on the moon's surface, or the equipment taken along to make the trip possible?

Comment: NASA have extensive documentation on this, including, "Payload projects are also assigned a risk classification depending on factors such as criticality to .... determine what the decision points are and what decision trees should be used for addressing." Read https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/423715main_NPR_7120-5_HB_FINAL-02-25-10.pdf